# Word for a society including many tribes

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I need a word that refers to a society in which there are many distinct tribes. I know a word tribal society, but it may refer to a single tribe not the whole society-I'm not sure though.

Comment: Hello, Shayan. I agree: there's not much hellp in the dictionaries with this. Even _multitribal_ is defined as 'relating to more than one tribe'. I think you're going to have to stick with 'a society consisting of / which includes many distinct tribes'.

Comment: I think a society is characterized as being one thing: Bronze Age society or a tribal society. Ergo, how can its constituent parts consist of different tribes?  A society is one thing. Anyway, tribal society is derogatory in some quarters (usages).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why doesn't multitribal work? A society with many ethnicities is multiethnic, one with many cultures is multicultural, doesn't multitribal work for one with many different tribes?

Comment: @Zebrafish It isn't incorrect, but it doesn't demand 'having many distinct tribes' with the usual implications of 'many' outside the maths domain.

Comment: @Edwin So you're saying it's not suitable because technically multitribal could mean just two tribes, and the OP asked for many tribes? I've looked up mult- prefix and first definition is "many, much, multiple", then the second one is "more than one".  If this is why you don't like the word, then if someone asked you what do you call a society with many different cultures and you said "multicultural" then "multicultural" wouldn't be a good word?

Comment: (b) Different definitions are listed by non-historic dictionaries (OED is the prime counterexample, being a historic dictionary) in order of frequency of use. Barring context clearly indicating otherwise, one should take the topmost sense as the default reading. // (a) 'Multitribal', not 'multi-' or 'multicultural', is the word in question here, and the only definitions I can find equate to 'pertaining to more than a single tribe'. This does not mirror the definitions given for 'multicultural'. Summing up, 'multitribal' _can_ be used for 'pertaining to / consisting of two tribes'. A hypernym.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not sure why you're confining it to "pertaining to /consisting of two tribes" if the meaning is more than one. More than one is an open meaning, not restricted to two. Words starting in multi- don't in any way lean more towards two as opposed to a larger number. There are other prefixes which mean two, every definition of multi- means more than one or many.

Comment: I'm not 'confining it' to 'pertaining to /consisting of two tribes'. I'm saying that it doesn't necessarily mean 'pertaining to /consisting of a lot of tribes', which is what 'pertaining to /consisting of many tribes' would be taken as meaning. In maths, certainly, many = more than 1 in the set of positive integers. But that's not the default meaning in everyday English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The best choice I found is multitribal. But because it was not an answer I just upvoted some comments. If you liked please put it as an answer so I can accept that.

Comment: Sorry, Shayan. I don't think it's close enough to merit 'answer' status. Feel free, of course, to use it; it's imprecise rather than incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the word is:

> confederacy/confederation

If you look at the Iroquois native Americans, they are what's called a confederacy.

> The Iroquois are a historically powerful northeast Native American
>   confederacy.
>
> ...comprising the Mohawk, Onondaga, Oneida, Cayuga, and Seneca. After
>   1722, they accepted the Tuscarora people from the Southeast into their
>   confederacy, and became known as the "Six Nations".
>   [Iroquois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois)

All the aforementioned native groups are tribes.

> The Iroquois have absorbed many other peoples into their tribes as a
>   result of warfare, adoption of captives, and by offering shelter to
>   displaced peoples.
>   [Iroquois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroquois)

From the Encyclopaedia Britannica:

> Five Nations (later Six Nations) better known as the Iroquois
>   Confederacy.
>   [Iroquois People](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Iroquois-people)

Notice the word "confederation" in the following:

> Iroquois Confederacy, also called Iroquois League, Five Nations, or
>   (from 1722) Six Nations, confederation of five (later six) Indian
>   tribes across upper New York
>   [Iroquois Confederacy](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Iroquois-Confederacy)

The word is also used when referring to the Twelve Tribes of Israel from the Bible/Torah. Here they are called a confederation:

> In the Bible's version of events, the period from the conquest of
>   Canaan under the leadership of Joshua until the formation of the first
>   Kingdom of Israel, passed with the tribes forming a loose
>   confederation, described in the Book of Judges.
>   [Twelve Tribes of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Tribes_of_Israel)

Another example is the confederacy of the Gallic tribes under Vercingetorix who led the rebellion against Julius Caesar:

> Vercingetorix was named the king of the Arverni and general of the
>   confederates.
>  [Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Vercingetorix)

Generally these two words are used. Probably less commonly "coalition" is used.

Also, if it's of any help, the adjective form is confederative or confederal. So you may say a confederal/confederative tribal society or group. This would mean that they are not separate or generally hostile against each other, because, well, they're confederates.

Comment: Thank you, but indeed what I mean is some tribes living next to each other without any alliance.

Comment: Generally a society not in alliance with each other experiences civil unrest or even breaks out into civil war.  So I'm not sure what you're picturing as a multi-tribal society who aren't allied with each other. Anyway, it's your word.

Comment: In the current time, what you state may be reasonable. However, in ancient times when the population was very low, did the tribes living, e.g., in Arabian Peninsula had an alliance? Maybe not.

Comment: @Shayan I'm not understanding what you need, but how about "intertribal"? I've added definitions to my answer.

Comment: Intertribal means between tribes.

Comment: @Lambie did you read the definitions? What's wrong with between? Ethnic groups share lands between themselves. Also the Oxford one: "Involving members of more than one tribe. ‘an intertribal group’"

Comment: intertribal means between tribes; it does not mean living side by side....

Comment: @Lambie I assume you still haven't seen the dictionary definitions I gave. It does not have to mean intertribal warfare, it can mean living among each other, like intermarriage. Admittedly multitribal, which is Edwin's idea, is a better adjective.

Comment: intertribal is anything between tribes, not just warfare. Intertribal customs, intertribal ceremonies, intertribal relationships. There is a basic difference between things in something ( a society, a group) and relationships between between groups.

Comment: @Lambie You're making the etymological fallacy that because prefix inter- generally means "between" in an exclusively isolated way that that meaning applies to all words beginning with inter-. Take interethnic:  "Of, relating to, involving, or representing different ethnic groups: an interethnic marriage; interethnic political coalitions." intertribal: "Involving members of more than one tribe. ‘an intertribal group’" You simply keep parroting your claim and deny these dictionary definitions exist.

Comment: intertribal cannot mean what the OP asked:  "Word for a society including many tribes". An inter-ethnic marriage is a marriage of the member of one ethnic group with another.  Between members of two groups.

Comment: @Lambie Also, I deleted intertribal not because you're right in your objection, but because I realised Edwin provided a better word "multitribal" which the OP didn't seem to accept. Given that, I deleted it. And really don't know what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Ok, thank you for understanding that I understood.

Comment: @Lambie If you say so, Chief Overlord Lexicographer over all authoritative dictionaries. I'm not even going provide the definitions again that show you are being fallacious in your argument, because you simply don't listen, you just jump like a broken record.

Comment: @Lambie Right about interethnic marriage,  so now try to refute the dictionary's example sentence of an "interethnic political coalition" "involving, or representing different ethnic groups"

Comment: I fear we have an English-language issue here. I am saying exactly what  the dictionaries say and that's why the term inter-tribal does not work here. You think I am saying something different from the dictionaries; I am not. :). An inter-ethnic political coalition is a coalition between two different ethnic groups. If you think that is not what it means, your mother tongue must not be English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76380/discussion-between-zebrafish-and-lambie).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 'heterogeneous', e.g. 'the country is a heterogeneous society comprised of three northern tribes'. But there are quite good answers here so which one will work perfectly for you is only depending on the context, I guess.

By the way, I hope what you write about is not of this modern era. As the word 'tribe' connotes 'primative', 'uncivilised', taking 'tribe' instead of 'ethnicity' can be seen as derogatory, you know, esp. for sjw.

Answer (score 0):

**[plural society](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plural_society)** (noun)

> A society composed of different ethnic groups or cultural traditions,
>   or in the political structure of which ethnic or cultural differences
>   are reflected.

'*Britain has been developing into an increasingly  plural society*'.

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tribe) adds the caveat that tribes are 'social divisions in a **traditional** society', and that the use of the term in a developed society is seen as derogatory: '1.2 _derogatory_  A distinctive or close-knit group.
"she made a stand against the social codes of her English middle-class tribe’' '.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard expressions using the word **nation**. From *crystalinks.com*:

Apache **Nation**. Apache is the collective name for several culturally related tribes of Native Americans, aboriginal inhabitants of North America, who speak a Southern Athabaskan language.

From *Wikipedia*:

The Seminole **Nation** of Oklahoma is a federally recognized Native American tribe based in the U.S. state of Oklahoma

Comment: I am inclined to think that this is actually the correct answer to the question posed - a 'nation' - but you have not given any links to your research and I think you need to expand the answer somewhat to earn an up-vote.

Comment: @NigelJ The definitions I've looked up for Nation is "tribe" or "confederation" or "federation" of tribes. Isn't that what my answer gave?

Comment: @Zebrafish I was commenting on the answer given by Stu W, not your  own answer. My own view is that Stu W's answer is correct - tribes, together, form a _nation_. I am just encouraging Stu W to go that little bit further and earn the up-vote. Your answer appearst o be 'confederacy'.

Comment: @NigelJ confederacy and confederation, I've made citations of both. The Nation definitions I've seen include those two, and also includes "federation". Also, from what I understand often a Nation can refer to a single tribe. I've seen this in all the dictionaries, and for example in the Iroquois example the six Nations comprising the Iroquois were single tribes. The other three words exclude just a single tribe (has to be at least 2). Apart from all that, the OP doesn't want any of my suggestions, and doesn't want multitribal or intertribal either, so I'm kind of confused.